# Laravel Eager Loading Optimization Comments Issue

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

So I was just messing with the eager loading stuff and I have been checking out how many Sql statements I have been pulling, I really feel what I have here does work but I feel like I could do this in a better way with eager loading. Does anyone have any suggestions or maybe a way to stop each comment from running a query?...

Here Is My Controller function called **Show()**

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $posts = Post::with(['user','comments'])->where('user_id', $id)->get();

    foreach($posts as $post) {
      echo "<hr /><h2>" . $post->title . "</h2>";
      echo "<p><u style='font-size: 0.8rem;'>By: ". $post->user->name ."</i></u> | <u style='font-size: 0.8rem;'>Date:" . $post->created_at->format('n-j-Y') . "</u>";
      echo "<br />" . $post->content . "</p><hr />";
      echo "<h3>Comments</h3>";
      if($post->comments->isNotEmpty()) {
        foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
          echo "<u>" . $comment->user->name . "</u><br />" . $comment->comment . "<br /><br />";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Sorry there are no comments yet.";
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the data it pulls and displays on the page I call. Please keep in mind I know I should use a view but I'm mostly doing this for the sake of learning.

> select * from `posts` where `user_id` = ?
>
> select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?)
>
> select `comments`.*, `taggables`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`,
>   `taggables`.`taggable_id` as `pivot_taggable_id`,
>   `taggables`.`taggable_type` as `pivot_taggable_type` from `comments`
>   inner join `taggables` on `comments`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_id`
>   where `taggables`.`post_id` in (?, ?, ?) and
>   `taggables`.`taggable_type` = ?

**Posts Web Page:**

---

**Bad Ass Title**

By: Moriah Mayer | Date:7-30-2018

Deserunt iure recusandae consequatur alias. Et non ratione unde deleniti. Est delectus recusandae consectetur quia tempore. Asperiores ea et voluptas molestias.

---

**Comments**

> select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1

Julia Mante V

This is a random Post comment hope it works.

> select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1

Moriah Mayer

This is another random Post comment hope it works.

---

**New PHP Title**

By: Moriah Mayer | Date:7-30-2018

This is our first content ever we created with out a tutorial.

---

**Comments**

> select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1

Timmothy Fay DDS

That is a interesting post that you have here.

---

**Moriahs Amazing Post**

By: Moriah Mayer | Date:7-30-2018

Here we will be showing you what we can do with our mind set to the project there are so many things you can learn from this post.

---

**Comments**

Sorry there are no comments yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to eager load the `user` related to each `comment`. You can eager load nested relationships using dot notation:

```
$posts = Post::with(['user', 'comments.user'])->where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

Now each comment will have its user eager loaded and will not run a new query.

Comment: in addition to @patricus answer .. please do not use the controller as your view ..

Comment: Thank you so Much that worked I feel dumb though it was right in the documentation lol. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I also said in the post I was just using the controller as the view just for learning reasons this is not for a real world application.